# Excel item value data to line graphs with labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a data set like this:

```
Set   Type   x   y
S1     A     1   24
S1     A     2   87
S1     A     3   33
S1     B     1   66
S1     B     2   11
S1     B     3   20
S1     C     1   79
S1     C     2   48
S1     C     3   87
S2     A     1   5
S2     A     2   73
S2     A     3   49
S2     B     1   56
S2     B     2   14
S2     B     3   13
S2     C     1   60
S2     C     2   32
S2     C     3   61
```

I want to make a scatter plot in Excel that groups points based on their labels. In this case, I have (`x`,`y`) coordinates for different data sets (`S1`, `S2`) and different experiment setups (`A`, `B`, `C`). I want to plot all of the results together, but I want one separate line per configuration (combination):

```
S1-A
S1-B
S1-C
S2-A
S2-B
S2-C
```

How do I do this in Excel 2013?

While some might say that I should transform my data, it's difficult to do in my scenario, because I have many more columns to consider and many samples. Ultimately, I will want a chart that filters out the "Type C" results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an automated way to do this, but you can "build" it manually.  First you need to create single labels, which you can do by concatenating Set and Type.  Use column E for that.  So E2 would be:

```
       =A2&B2      for S1A
    or =A2&"-"&B2  if you want a hyphen in the middle: S1-A
```

Copy that down the column.  Now create a scatter chart with the first group.  Highlight C2:D4 and insert a scatter chart.  That creates the framework to add the other series.  Click on Select Data.  The first step is to change the label for the first series.  Select the series, click Edit, and change the Series Name to point to cell E2.

Click on Add and it will bring up a dialog box for another series.  For the Series Name, point to cell E5.  For the X values, select C5:C7.  For the Y values, select D5:D7.  Note that Excel pre-fills a placeholder entry for Y.  Delete that before pasting the real value or it will concatenate the real value to what is there.

Repeat the process for each series.

If you don't want minor subdivisions on the X axis, right-click on the axis.  Select Format Axis.  That will give you access to complete customization.